# tabular display in r of one column nested under another

Tags: r

I have two columns in a data frame, the Store Number (113 values) and the Cluster Number that store  "belongs to" that has six values (1-6):

> pct_v2[c("StoreNumber","groups_pct")]

```
StoreNumber groups_pct

         1          1

         2          2

         4          3

         5          4

         6          2

         9          5

        10          5

        12          4

        20          1

        23          4
```

I would like to create a table where the group_pct values are columns and the cell  entries are the values of the StoreNumber column:

```
                              Group_pct
      2          3          4          5          6
     ----------------------------------------------
      1          2          4          5          9
     20          6                    12         10
                                      23
```

could this be done in the tidyverse?

Answer (score 0):

```
pct <- structure(list(StoreNumber = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 23L), groups_pct = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L), i = 1:10), .Names = c("StoreNumber", "groups_pct", "i"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

It's not beautiful, but you can use:

```
library(tidyr)
pct$i <- 1:10 # required for spread, then discarded with [-1]
pct2 <- lapply(spread(pct, groups_pct, StoreNumber)[-1], na.omit)
str(pct2)
# List of 5
#  $ 1: atomic [1:2] 1 20
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:8] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
#  $ 2: atomic [1:2] 2 6
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:8] 1 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ 3: atomic [1:1] 4
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:9] 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ 4: atomic [1:3] 5 12 23
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:7] 1 2 3 5 6 7 9
#  $ 5: atomic [1:2] 9 10
#   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10

pct3 <- lapply(pct2, function(l) c(l, rep(NA, max(lengths(pct2))-length(l))))
str(pct3)
# List of 5
#  $ 1: int [1:3] 1 20 NA
#  $ 2: int [1:3] 2 6 NA
#  $ 3: int [1:3] 4 NA NA
#  $ 4: int [1:3] 5 12 23
#  $ 5: int [1:3] 9 10 NA

as.data.frame(pct3)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  2  4  5  9
# 2 20  6 NA 12 10
# 3 NA NA NA 23 NA
```

So ... it's hard to get what you want with the tidyverse. I'm guessing there are ways to incorporate it into some of these steps, but you're really munging some data to get to this point.